# Books on a shelf (Counting Problem)

Tags: combinatorics

The following question is causing me some trouble:

> You have 12 books (6 are black, 4 red, 1 blue and 1 yellow) to put next to each other with one condition: all the black ones need to be together.

My intuition would be to consider all the black book as one, and then to take all the possible permutations of the black books into consideration.
Which would give me: 7!6! .

But this differs from the answer written in my book which is 12!/(4!6!)
In my mind, this result doesn't represent the idea of all the black books being next to each other.

Would appreciate if anyone could help me on this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe they are assuming books of a given colour are identical.

Comment: Neither your attempt nor the answer in the book have anything to do with *probability*.  These are counting problems which are generally given the label "combinatorics" or "enumerative combinatorics" if you wish to be more specific.  It only becomes a probability question if you ask something like "what is the *probability* that if we put books up at random that all the black books are together"

Comment: thanks, I edited

Comment: That being said, the answer supposedly written in the book for this problem is incorrect.  The answer of $\frac{12!}{4!6!\color{grey}{1!1!}}$ is the answer to the question of "how many ways can we arrange books on a shelf where there are six black books, four red books, one blue, and one yellow where books are indistinguishable except by color with *no other conditions*.  This in particular fails to take into account anything related to the black books being together.  Had we treated the books as being indistinguishable except by color, that should have been $\frac{7!}{4!}$ if black together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct!

The answer given in your book, $\frac{12!}{4!6!}$, is the number of ways to put these $12$ books on shelf without any restriction on the position, and by considering identical the books of the same colour.

If we assume that the books of the same colour are identical and if we apply the restriction that black books stay together, then the number of ways is
$\frac{7!}{4!}$.

On the other hand, if we assume that the books of the same colour are **not** identical with the restriction that black books stay together, then the number of ways is $7!6!$.

Answer (score 2):

If books of same colour are same then (assume all black 6 books as one) so total ways

$$\frac{7!.6!}{6!.4!.1!.1!}$$

If books are different then

$${7!.6!}$$